# catkin_make install only selected packages

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a catkin workspace that contains multiple packages, however I would like to install the catkin workspace to a Install directory, with only a few selected packages instead of all packages. Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256587/catkin_make-install-only-selected-packages/) by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_make --help`

leads to

> `--pkg PKG [PKG ...]   Invoke 'make' on specific packages only`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1